# SVN with Lighttpd web server?

Tags: 10.04, server, 9.04, lighttpd, svn

I need to install svn on Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu 9.04. On both servers I use lighttpd.

I found some tutorials on internet explaining which packages to install with Apache, but i actually need lighttpd.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a posting in lighty forum:

> There is no mod_subversion for lighttpd and there won't be one in the 
>   near future. lighttpd is single-threaded (mostly) and mod_subversion 
>   would block the whole server process (and so ALL connections).
>   Either proxy to apache or use svnserve which has almost all features 
>   which mod_subversion has (the only problem I can think of is that Apache 
>   supports several authentication modules (kerberos etc.) which can be 
>   used in combination with mod_subversion, but svnserve doesn't support 
>   that iirc).

Your best choice is to use apache2 in combination with lighty: [A great tutorial](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/ApacheSubversionRecipe).